# When I am web scraping in python using findAll from BeautifulSoup and regex (re.compile), I cannot loop it properly using css classes

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am new to BeautifulSoup and Python.  So, On this WP website, there are 4 articles on the homepage, but it only gives me 3 articles and hence 3 images attached to it.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://ionnews.mu", headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html5lib")
articles = bsObj.findAll("article", {"class": "post"})
print(len(articles))

for article in articles:
  image = bsObj.findAll("img", {"src": re.compile("/wp-content/uploads/.*.jpg")})
  print(image)
```

Comment: When I visit the website, I can only see 3 too? Can you check the website again if there are 4 articles or 3?

Comment: Did you mean `article` elements or the posts? If you mean `article` elements, there are 4 of them but one of them doesn't have class attribute of `post`, it has `page`.

Comment: I checked the website, it's weird, a few hours ago, when I was testing, I saw 4 posts, with article tags.  Maybe it was a cache issue and python showed me an updated version.

But for the last 6 lines, is it possible to use some sort of embedded findAll function and regex and get all the images directly instead of using the for loop, such as 'a.featured-image img'.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have figured out article count thing, there is no simpler solution indeed. There maybe some other versions if you wanna check out.

Your code in simplified version is:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://ionnews.mu", headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")
articles = bsObj.findAll("article", {"class": "post"})

for article in articles:
    print(article.find("img").get("src"))
```

And there is this version, which utilizes inline for loop

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://ionnews.mu", headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")
images = [article.find("img").get("src") for article in bsObj.findAll("article", {"class": "post"})]

print(images)
```

There is the approach with `lxml`, it's not quite good, but you can use this to find elements easily if they are in some weird places using `xpath`:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://ionnews.mu", headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
lxmlHtml = etree.HTMLParser()

htmlPage = etree.parse(html, lxmlHtml)

images = htmlPage.xpath("//article[contains(@class, 'post') and not(contains(@class, 'page'))]//img")

for image in images:
    print(image.attrib["src"])
```

Comment: Niiiiice.  That's great, I tried the first 2 solutions and they both worked.  So here, the solution was not to use regex but to simply use the the find and findAll functions.  

I should point out the second soln, the one with the inline loop, provides the images inside an array, so if anyone wants to display same as the first solution, I can just add a line 

''for image in images: print(image)''

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with the right solution without using regex

thank you Guven Degirmenci, please see code below

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://ionnews.mu", headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html5lib")

images = [article.find("img").get("src")
          for article
          in bsObj.findAll
          ("article", {"class": "post"})]
for image in images:
    print(image)
```